# Cannot get Scanner to See File

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner, java-io

I cannot understand why I can't get scanner to read my .txt file. In the end I resorted to just storing the data as a String in my program. But I would still like to know why Scanner is not seeing this file.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
```

I've also tried:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/Test.txt"));
```

Both result in FileNotFoundException being thrown.

The text file is located at the same directory where the class files and the source files are.

Does anyone know what's wrong??

Ok well this really sucks. I just don't know why this is happening. I know for a fact the file exists.

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

shows that the directory I'm in is the correct one.

Anyone else have any thoughts?

Comment: Are you certain the file is really there?  Can you open an explorer and dump in the path?

Comment: In the first case, the file needs to be in the current directory, not necessarily ' the same directory where the class files and the source files are'. In the second case you must have got the filename wrong.

Comment: As @Tim has rightly pointed out, the path is a invalid one. Windows paths are supposed to contain backslashes

Comment: @vikasn91 No, they don't.  I just tested both on IntelliJ running on Windows and they both work.

Comment: Specify the file path correctly, `Scanner scan = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\myusername\\Desktop\\Test.txt")); `

Comment: @Tim, windows paths in eclipse need an escape character If it's running on linux

Comment: But _not_ if they are forward slashes, only backslashes.  And if he used unescaped backslashes his code would not even _compile_, which would give him a different error than the one he posted here.

Comment: I believe that all Windows systems since Windows 2000 have allowed forward slashes in file names (as did Windows NT) and treated them equivalently to backslashes.  (On a DOS command line, they don't always work because the command-line parser may interpret `/` as the start of an option.  But the function that looks for files doesn't use the command-line parser.)

Comment: @ajb **Java** has supported forward slashes in filenames on all platforms since at least 1997.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strip down the problem by omitting the Scanner and start with the file only:

```
File myFile = new File("Test.txt");
myFile.exists();
myFile.canRead();
...
```

Then continue with analyzing the path of the file:

```
myFile().getCanonicalPath();
...
```

The scanner wouldn't have any problem if the java process would be able to access the file.

If that does not lead anywhere, we'll need more infos: which version of java? How do you start the java process?

Comment: What exactly is the point of calling Boolean methods and ignoring their return values?

Comment: That were only hints for J'Zargo what to do in order to track down the problem - should have been obvious enough (and was for J'Zargo, as a matter of fact...)

Comment: You haven't answered the question I asked. This does not provide an answer to the question. It should have been posted as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the file you are trying to access is `read-only` or not. If it is `read-only` then uncheck it. Or you can try this also:

```
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/Test.txt"));
Scanner scan=new Scanner(fis);
```

Comment: For a plain text file, I don't think permissions would be an issue unless he explicitly were tinkering with them.  I didn't downvote you by the way, it was @EJP.

Comment: Why? He's only trying to read from it. Why would read-only permission prevent reading? The code change you've suggested won't make any difference either.

Comment: It sometimes may throw exception while reading also [see here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileNotFoundException.html)

Comment: @jcool Reading from a read-only file doesn't cause exceptions. If the read-only attribute was a problem it would throw an exception on opening, not on reading. `new Scanner(File)` will throw exactly the same `FileNotFoundException` as your code. Internally it does something similar to the code you posted. There is no improvement.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You have precisely zero information about who downvoted this answer. It's a secret ballot. You have no business speculating about it, let alone publishing your guesswork as fact.

Comment: @EJB OK fair enough.  But I saw the downvote happen almost precisely when you published your comment.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Correlation is not causation.

Answer (score -1):

Ok well I fixed it. It seems Torgeist was right. It does help to strip down the problem. It was very useful to use `exists()` and `canRead()` since these were returning false.  Somewhere there must have been something wrong in the exact file path I was entering even though I copy and pasted. Weird...only other possible explanation is that something was blocking access to the desktop but that seems pretty unlikely.

The use of escaped backslashes or forward slashes made no difference.

```
File file = new File("C:/Users/UserName/Documents/Testing.txt");
```

vs.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\OCB\\Documents\\Testing.txt");
```

Both worked.

Comment: You fixed it how? If you don't provide a solution, this is not an answer.